# How to style the borders using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a css piece of code like this:

```
.profile img.profilePic {
  position: absolute;
  margin: -50px 70px 50px 50px;
  background: #2f293d;
  border: 1px solid #2f293d;
  padding: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: .2rem .2rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

Now, what if I want to change the   `border: 1px solid #2f293d;` in Javascript...???

I've tried :

```
var colorA = document.getElementsByClassName("profile img.profilePic")[userA_Index];
colorA.style.border = "1px solid #000";
```

and also:

```
var colorA = document.querySelector(".profile img.profilePic")[userA_Index];
colorA.style.border = "1px solid #000"
```

With no success.

Note: I already did such styling using the code below but borders...

```
var colorA = document.getElementsByClassName("level")[userA_Index];
colorA.style="font-family:verdana; color:red; font-size:20;"
```

Any help to solve this is greatly appreciated...

Comment: please show your html and also value of `userA_Index`

Comment: Maybe it's better if I add the entire code...

Comment: I have added the CodePen...Please take a quick look at it... Unfortunately none of the above work for me...

Comment: First off, you are using `getElementsByClassName("profile img.profilePic")` wrong, read [here how-to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), second, your are suppose to provide a [mcve], **within the question**, not as an external link

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(".row").css({"border" : "1px solid #000","padding" : "5px"});
```

```html
You can use JQuery as well

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      $(".row").css({"border" : "1px solid #000","padding" : "5px"});
    </script>
    <div class="row"> Hello World</div>
```

Comment: OP doesn't use `jQuery` (and question is not tagged with it either), so if to post answers with it, ask first if that is an option.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach to solve this problem is by Creating a custom css class like `custom-border`

```
img.profilePic.custom-border {
   border: 1px solid #000
}
```

and in javascript

```
document.querySelector(".profile img.profilePic").classList.add("custom-border");
```

To avoid `undefined` error you have to be sure about the path in `querySelector`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LvrxyG

Comment: Thanks for the answer Plus one ... I get this error each time:  Cannot read property 'add' of undefined at Script.js:374

Comment: try `querySelector` instead of  `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: I already did this kind of styling (Not for borders)... like :

Comment: var colorA = document.getElementsByClassName("level")[userA_Index];
colorA.style="font-family:verdana; color:red; font-size:20;"

Comment: look at my naswer I add `classList` after the retuned element just like `document.getElementsByClassName("...").classList.add("custom-border");`

Comment: also it's import make sure that your quering the right element with your query `profile img.profilePic`

Comment: @LGSon my answer works, just i didn't pay attention to `getElementsByClassName ` i tought it was `querySelector `

Comment: Then What I'm missing... @Youssef can you please fork my code with your working solution on CodePen..

Comment: I assumed OP had an element with `class="profile profilePic"`, which they might not, hence removed my comments now, mainly because now your syntax is correct

Comment: @Youssef, Thanks, Youssef for the CodePen... yes you're right but I'm trying to make it work on my own code... Please take a look at my CodePen JS lines 356 to 370... These lines are responsible for all those special styles of "Reza Xohammadi " (The red colored user on the leaderboard) ... I want to make changes in borders of his profile picture too... But I need a hand :(

Comment: @SaraRee you have just to target the right element in your `querySelector` ... check carefully your query

Answer (score -1):

So you only want change the border color. If then you can achieve it easily by "borderColor" property. See following snippet:

```js
document.querySelector("#setBorder").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  document.querySelector(".profilePic").style.borderColor = "#000";
}
```

```css
.profile img.profilePic {
  position: aabsolute;
  margin: -50px 70px 50px 50px;
  background: #2f293d;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  padding: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: .2rem .2rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="profile">
  <img class="profilePic" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
</div>
<button id="setBorder"> Click on me</button>
```